# How to get the coefficients of the polynomial in python

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials, coefficients

I need to create a function `get_polynom` that will take a list of tuples `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)` representing points and find the coefficients of the polynomial `c0, c1, ..., cn`.

I can't manage to understand the task, the only tip I have is the provided part of the function:

```
import numpy as np


def get_polynom(coords):
    ...
    return np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

Have somebody done something similar? Just a little explanation of what exactly is expected would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial is a function `f(x) = cn x^n + ... + c1 x + c0`. With the pair of tuples you get n+1 equations of the form `f(xi) = yi` for i going from 1 to n+1. If you substitute `xi` and `yi` in the first equation, you obtain a linear system of n equations, with the unknowns `cn` to `c0`. Writing this in matrix form, you get `A*C = B`.

The `a` argument of the `np.linalg.solve` represents the `A` matrix, in this case the "weights" of the polynomial coefficients - that is the powers of x (e.g. one row will be `[xi^n, xi^(n-1), ..., xi, 1]`). The `b` argument will be the vector of `yi`.

Note that if your polynomial is of degree n, you need n+1 tuples to solve for its coefficients.

Comment: So, basically, if I have three pairs of `(x, y)`, I will have three equations, each of which will look like `y = 1 * c0 + x * c1 + x^2 * c2 + x^3 * c3`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just note that you need a number of equations equal to the number of coefficients to be able to solve the linear system. So if you get 3 tuples, then the equation will be just `y = 1 * c0 + x * c1 + x^2 * c2`. I'm updating my answer to reflect this

Comment: Oh, okay, got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an example, if you have a first degree polynomial `y = a * x + b`, and the points `(1, 2)` and `(2, 3)`, you obtain 2 equations `a + b = 2` and `2a + b = 3`